# List Orders with datePaid is within last 14 days using the Element API plugin

Tags: plugin-craftcommerce, plugin-elementapi

I want to list the orders with `datePaid` is within last 14 days. But I cannot workout the correct criteria, and I don't know if `isPaid` works correctly as well:

```
'criteria' => [
    'dateUpdated' => '>=' . date('Y-m-d'.' 00:00:00', strtotime("-14 days")),
    'isPaid' => '1',
],
```

Comment: You said you're looking for `datePaid`, but your code example is using `dateUpdated`.  Not sure if it's affecting your results, but ` 00:00:00` is probably unnecessary. `isPaid` should probably be a boolean. i.e. `'isPaid' => true`.

Comment: If none of that helps, try posting the rest of your element API config... could be something else in there.

Comment: don't know why i type `dateUpdated` when i was thinking `datePaid`. Thanks, and now things fixed!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's an example `elementapi.php` that should get you going...this is returning shipping details but you can modify the transformer for whatever data you need of course...

```
return [
'endpoints' => [
    'api/json/orders/whatever.json' =>  [
        'paginate' => false,
        'elementType' => 'Commerce_Order',
        'criteria' =>   ['dateOrdered' => '>'. date('Y-m-d', strtotime("-2 weeks")),
                         'isPaid' => true,
                        ],

        'transformer' => function(Commerce_OrderModel $order) {
            return [
            "id" => $order->ISOrderNumber,   
            "fullname" => $order->shippingAddress->firstName ?? '' . " " . $order->shippingAddress->lastName ?? '',
            "firstname" => $order->shippingAddress->firstName ?? '',
            "lastname" => $order->shippingAddress->lastName ?? '',    
            "company" => $order->shippingAddress->businessName ?? '',
            "street1" => $order->shippingAddress->address1 ?? '',
            "street2" => $order->shippingAddress->address2 ?? '',
            "suburb" => $order->shippingAddress->city ?? '',
            "state" => $order->shippingAddress->stateName ?? '',
            "postcode" => $order->shippingAddress->zipCode ?? '',
            "phone" => $order->shippingAddress->phone ?? '',
            "mobile" => $order->shippingAddress->phone ?? '',
            "email" => $order->email ?? '', 
            ];
        },
    ], 

    // Next api thing to go here...

],
```

];